# Firestore with getDownloadURL in vuex store

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore, vuex, firebase-storage

I'm having real difficulties with combining onSnapshot with getDownloadURL in my actions and setting it on mutations to change my state in vuex. I keep getting "[vuex] do not mutate vuex store state outside mutation handlers" error.

Here is a sample of my code:

```
state = () => ({
  products:[]
})

mutations = {
 setProducts(state, products) {
        state.products = products
        console.log(state.products)
    },
}

actions = {
  setProducts({commit}) {
        let colRef = collection(db, 'products')
        const unsub = onSnapshot(colRef, snapshot => {
            let products = []
            snapshot.docs.forEach(doc => {
                const imageDownloadURL = getDownloadURL(ref(storage, `${doc.data().imageRef}`))
                .then( url => {
                    // console.log(url)
                    products.push({
                        id: doc.id,
                        name: doc.data().name,
                        price: doc.data().price,
                        description: doc.data().description,
                        imageURL: url
                    })
                    commit('setProducts', products)
                })
            })
        })
    },
}
```

I've got a collection that looks like the following:

```
 {
   id: 1,
   name: 'NotPot Orange',
   price: '8.80',
   description: 'This is an orange flavour vitamin',
   imageURL: 'images/notpot1.jpg'
},
```

My console.log gives the data I want in this output:

```
 {
    id: 'qv1t4f2NfAo9N4YrkXzg',
    name: 'NotPot Citrus',
    price: '6.50',
    description: 'This is a citrus flavour vitamin',
    imageURL: 'https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/blahblahblah- 
               project.appspot.com/o/images%2Fnotpot5.jpg?alt=media&token=385a5a25-ef2c'
  },
```

I've got a getter which I grab in my v-for:

```
  getters = {
    products: (state) => {
        return state.products
    },
  }
```

like so:

```
  <feature-product
     v-for="product in this.$store.getters.products"
     :key="product.id"
     :product="product"
  />
```

Am I missing smth? I'm really not so versed with onSnapshot and getDownloadURL - so I feel like it's a mistake somewhere there. I heard smth about needing to deepClone/deepCopy but not sure what that means. Any clue or point to the right direction will help out loads! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I'm still not 100% sure if this is the correct method - but I got it to work with `{getDocs} from 'firebase/firestore'` along side `{ref, getDownloadURL} from 'firebase/storage'`

I decided to drop the aforementioned real-time data pull to just getDocs in one go - so its not exactly how I wanted it but I thought it's still applicable to my use case. Here's my changes:

```
actions = {
    async setProducts({commit}) {
        let colRef = collection(db, 'products')
        const querySnapshot = await getDocs(colRef)
        querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
            let products
            const imageDownloadURL = getDownloadURL(ref(storage, `${doc.data().imageRef}`))
            .then( url => {
                // console.log(url)
                products = ({
                    id: doc.id,
                    name: doc.data().name,
                    price: doc.data().price,
                    description: doc.data().description,
                    imageURL: url
                })
                commit('setProducts', products)
            })
        })
    }
  }
```

changes to my mutations:

```
mutations = {
    setProducts(state, products) {
        state.products.push(products)
        console.log(state.products)
    },
}
```

P.S. to get it to be load at the earliest possible point - you can use `beforeCreated()` or `created()` lifecycle hooks to dispatch the 'setProducts' action.

Hope this helps for anyone else stuck on smth similar.